# How to change the interpolation mode of keyframes for material properties

Tags: animation

I want to change interpolation mode to constant for a value in a node in shader editor, but it's not even showing on the timeline, nor the graph editor

Comment: maybe you need to select the node?

Comment: We'll need more detail.  Can you show some screenshots or, better, attach your blend file to your question? (Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.)